# pass value to data-target

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editeventmodal" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button></a>
```

I also have an `<%= data[i].ID %>` value that I want to use to pass it through.

this is inside an `ejs` for loop, which when i click this button, it renders the `data-target`. This below is the `data-target`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editeventmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelLogout"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelLogout">Edit Event</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <% if (data.length) {
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                data[i].DATE = data[i].DATE.split(" ");
                data[i].DATE = data[i].DATE[0];
                if (data[i].DATE.length == 4) {
                  data[i].DATE = "0" + data[i].DATE;
                }

                data[i].ENDDATE = data[i].ENDDATE.split(" ");
                data[i].ENDDATE = data[i].ENDDATE[0];
                if (data[i].ENDDATE.length == 4) {
                  data[i].ENDDATE = "0" + data[i].ENDDATE;
                }
                %>
            <form action="/addevent" method="post">
              <input type="text" id="" name="nameofevent" value="<%= data[i].EVENT_NAME %> " required>
              <input type="text" name="eventdate" id="" value="<%= currentDate %>" readonly>
              <br>
              <br>
              <!-- <input type="text" name="eventstarttime" id="" placeholder="Start Time"> -->
              <!-- <input type="text" name="eventstarttimeampm" id="" placeholder="AM or PM"> -->
              <label for="eventstarttime">Event Start Time</label>
              <% console.log("Start TImE! ", data[i].DATE ) %>

              <input type="time" name="eventstarttime" id="eventstarttime" value="<%= data[i].DATE %>">
              <br>
              <br>
              <label for="eventendtime">Event End Time</label>
              <% console.log("Start TImE! ", data[i].ENDDATE ) %>

              <input type="time" name="eventendtime" id="eventendtime" value="<%= data[i].ENDDATE %>">
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="eventlocation" id="" placeholder="Event Location">
              <br>
              <br>
              <select class="select2-multiple form-control" name="selectedclient" required>
                <option disabled selected="true">Select Client</option>
                <% if (clientlist.length) {
                  for(var i = 0; i < clientlist.length; i++) { %>
                    <option value="<%=clientlist[i].USERNAME%>"><%=clientlist[i].FIRST_NAME%> <%=clientlist[i].LAST_NAME%></option>
                <%  }
                } else { %>
              <% } %>
              </select>
              <!-- <div class="input-group-prepend"> -->
                <!-- <div class="dropdown-menu"> -->
                <!-- </div> -->
              <!-- </div> -->
              <!-- <input type="text" name="selectedclient" id="" placeholder="Selected Client"> -->
            
            <!-- <p>Are you sure you want to logout?</p> -->
          </div>
          <%  }
          } else { %>
           <td><a href="/addclient?p=1"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        <% } %>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Event</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So within the `for loop` of the button at the top (the first piece of code posted), I should be able to click the button and it pops up this `modal` dynamically with the value of document. how can i pass through the `<%= data[i].ID %>` value so that it knows which one to pop up through the `data-target`

Comment: You can add other data attributes to the button and use the modal events to get the data from target button. Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: oh okay. @charlietfl v 4.3.1

Comment: So you can access the button that was clicked using the modal events